# How to access ActiveMQ web console in Wildfly 10.1.0?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I know Wildfly 10.1.0 comes with ActiveMQ Artemis as its default JMS broker and that's fine.
I also know when running ActiveMQ outside Wildfly as a standalone application you are able to access its web console.
My question is how to access/activate/enable this webconsole just using the Wildfly 10.1.0 as it comes when downloaded? Is it necessary to make any configuration or deploy anything into wildfly?
I want to be able to check the JMS mesages content and the web console seems to suit that.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveMQ Artemis web console is a few web applications distributed with the standalone broker in the `web` directory. Theoretically you should be able to take these war files and deploy them in WildFly. They are:

- `activemq-branding.war`
- `artemis-plugin.war`
- `console.war`

That said, WildFly already has a management layer built-in which has a web console of its own along with a powerful CLI client. The management layer does things like modify the server's XML configuration behind-the-scenes when changes are made. The standalone ActiveMQ Artemis console will circumvent WildFly's management layer as it will communicate directly with the embedded Artemis broker via JMX. I've not done this before so it may not work at all, but as I said theoretically all you'll need is the war files for the standalone console.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Justin.
I deployed the three war files sucessfully but the console I see is a little different from the one I see when I run the ActiveMQ Artemis standalone.
It seems to not have the same features like check the messagens content, create queues, etc.

Comment: It's hard to tell without a screenshot, but it sounds like you're seeing the console that ships with WildFly.